# Поиск элемента в файле

Tags: c#

Есть txt - файл вида: [Володя_Синяк #1 Охранник 5 лет], в котором #1 это номер отдела. Задача заключается в том, чтобы при вводе нужного отдела сортировало людей из этого отдела в порядке убывания стажа [5 лет].

В целом все понятно кроме одного - как найти в файле нужный мне отдел если подобных строк > 100?

Comment: А как вы находите если <= 100? Попробуйте делать точно так же.

Comment: мне в целом принцип не понятен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создаешь класс, с необходимыми полями
2. Считываешь данные файла в List<Названия твоего класса>
3. Делаешь на этим списком что-то типа `Where(person=>person.numOtd==<Место для номера отдела>).OrderByDescending(person=>person.staj)`